# How can I make the operating system think a directory is another directory?

Tags: git, ubuntu, directory

Basically, I want the computer to treat something like `/documents/folderB/` as `/documents/folderC`.

So basically any attempt on accessing `/documents/folderB/blahblah/` will be instead accessing `/documents/folderC/blahblah/`.

I'm trying to do this, because I feel like I need to submit a project 2 times, under different folders on git. However, the project is not completed yet, thus I want future updates to be applied in both locations. So I was wondering if I could link 2 directories into the same physical location.

Also, I'm working on Ubuntu, with git, code is in C. Not sure if those things are relevent though.

Comment: I am not quite sure why git would care how you name the local folder, or how having a symlink would help. Git is aware of symlinks inside of repositories. And if the two repository roots are symlinks for the same file, then you don't really have two repositories, either.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a symbolic link to do this.

Follow this answer - https://askubuntu.com/questions/56339/how-to-create-a-soft-or-symbolic-link

Comment: Just for completeness, Linux also supports the so-called "bind mounts" where a directory could be "mounted" just like a device to some other directory: `mount --bind olddir newdir`. This command can be used by super-user only.

Comment: Thanks. I thought symbolic link was what I need, but I didn't understood if I'm right.